# Add a "banner" to top and bottom of many photos

Tags: windows, image-processing, image-editor

I'm looking for a really simple (easy to use) piece of free software that can batch edit a large number of photos.

I have a bunch of photos from my youth sports team, and I just want to add a "banner" to the top and bottom of every photo that indicates the team's name. I'm not looking for very many bells and whistles; all I want is to control the text color and background color of a rectangular-shaped "banner."

Additionally, I do NOT want the "banner" to cover any part of the photo. Rather, I want the dimensions of the photo to expand to include the banner in addition to the full photo.

Is there any free software that would be able to accommodate these specifications?

Answer (score 1):

When you ask for "free software" and add in the parameter of image editing, my alleged mind automatically jumps to [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/).

[image: gimp logo]

I did a quick search for "batch mode Gimp" and found a link to a rather [simplistic tutorial](https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/) that may be of value. As the name of the tutorial includes the word "basic," one might presume that there are more advanced tutorials available for learning how to process batch image processing. One aspect of the above linked tutorial that caught my eye is that batched-Gimp can be configured to process all the images in a single directory/folder.

This would work well for you, I believe, especially if you have photos that are all the same resolution and size. You should be able to specify a series of steps to combine images with your desired banners.

Additional research shows that Gimp also integrates processing with Python. If you have those skills, you may be on the right track with Gimp.

There is also a [Gimp Plugin registry](http://registry.gimp.org/node/26259) to provide additional utilities and perhaps an easier interface from which to process your images.

The above linked site refers to a plug-in called BIMP.

[image: batch image manipulation plugin]

So many options!

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick did the trick. Once installed, I used the append command to recursively add banners to the top and bottom of every photo:

`for /R %g in (*.jpg) DO magick convert top_banner.png "%g" bottom_banner.png -append "%g-2".jpg`