# simplest possible linux graphical design/image processing program

Tags: image-editor

All I want to do is create simple rectangular images, choose the size, select rectangular areas, fill them with colors designated as #nnnnnn, center some text, choosing the font, and color similarly, and save the danged thing as a flat, plain image with no transparency. And it would be nice to be able to zoom the thing to a size mortal can see without a microscope while I work on it. What could be simpler?

I am neither stupid, nor technophobic. I've been messing with computers since the 1970s. I've had desktop PCs continuously since before the internet existed. I've been using nixes for a decade. I have perhaps a dozen bootable filesystems on this machine, 4 of which are in my fstab and my lilo.conf. I'm a member of Mensa and Intertel, for #@!'s sake.

But EVERY linux app I've tried to use for this sort of thing is INSANELY complicated and non-intuitive. I better never meet a gimp dev, because I might not be able to control my urge to give him a black eye. Simple tasks are hidden in windows that don't even open by default and are invoked 3 layers down in submenus of menus that have names that don't even remotely suggest their content, while the artsy-fartsy stuff fills the default interface with so many cutesy-pie buttons that none of them are big enough to even see, let alone guess what they are all for.

Anyone who isn't making images professionally and devotes a month to learning GIMP to do simple tasks is a fool. So don't even say the G word.

Is there anything suitable?

Answer (score 1):

A user (Matt) posted a request for [software to easily batch photos](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/42915/add-a-banner-to-top-and-bottom-of-many-photos) in order to add banner strips to each image. He later found his own answer, and apparently liked it better than my "plugins-for-G" suggestion (grin).

His self-discovered solution is a program called [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) which appears more complex than a GUI program, as it's a command line sort of software.

The description indicates that it does many things, including "create, edit, compose, or convert bitmap images." I don't fear the CLI world, but suggest that you might be able to generate your objective in a few words, based on Matt's response in his post and the opening page of the web site for ImageMagick

A resource from the web site also indicates a [forum](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/) for this program. Forums have been useful for everything I've pursued.

[image: ImageMagick Wizard]

Comment: Good idea. I have written some scripts using imagemagick as a matter of fact. It had entered my mind that it might be able to do this. It's only got a gazillion component programs, each with it's own half mile long man page. Perhaps I exaggerate. Slightly.I just can't shake the idea that there must be a simple turnkey solution I'm missing because I'm searching with the wrong strings.

Comment: I mention the possibility that I might be searching the wrong strings specifically because I've read threads like this where people get quite pushily pedantic focusing on the meta-question of whether the OP's objective is properly called 'foo' or 'bar' despite a clearly stated objective. Thanks for the suggestion. I'll pursue it if nothing simpler comes along.

Answer (score 1):

Often, the further back you go, the less complicated it was to do something. I would suggest `xpaint` and `xfig`, but also look at the drawing language `pic` we used before they decided you need a gui for everything.  `pic` is part of the `troff` toolset, which these days is the gnu `groff` package. 
(see *Making Pictures with GNU PIC* by Eric S. Raymond, August 1995 [postscript file](http://www.kohala.com/start/troff/gpic.raymond.ps))
 Here's how to draw a box in green with some text in it:

```
pic <<\! | groff | gv -
.PS
box shaded "green" "my text" 
.PE
!
```

[image]

Other simple-ish tools are libreoffice draw, and the online in the browser [draw.io](https://www.draw.io/).

Comment: Thanks, these are excellent suggestions, and the example is great. I'll revisit this when I've tested enough of these. "Often, the further back you go, the less complicated it was" - Ain't it the truth?